# Creating tiff 16 bit images and jpg thumbnails from it

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, tiff, magick++

I'm using magick++ to create 16 bit tiff images. They are monochromatic, so all three channels have the same values. Once the image is completed I create png or jpg thumbnails from it.

I can visualize the tiff and png images in Imagej perfectly. The jpg images can be visualized in Imagej but they lose a lot of color levels.

However, all the images (tiff, png and jpg) are black in another viewers like Gnome, Firefox, Imagemagick viewer or Shotwell.

Why? How can I see the images correctly in every viewer?

Comment: you should post here one of those problematic images

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Imagej automatically adjust the color window levels with the range of values in the image. The other viewers don't. So, to see nice images I had to adjust the levels of the images with magick++.